# android layout; Resizing colums of images so they fit the screen

Tags: android, android-layout

im trying to make my images fit nicely into screen without overlapping
but no matter what i do i cannot get them to scale properly.
I thought ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP would scale my images but probably im doing it all wrong. 
any help would be appreciated. (if you know simple function that will fix my problem then pls feel free to respond without reading my code which is mostly tutorial code anyways )

Here is what i got:
main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="75dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
/>
```

This is my HelloGrid.java file:

```
package com.grid.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HelloGrid extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //removes annoying title on top
          setContentView(R.layout.main);

            GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
            gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

            gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(HelloGrid.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
    }
}
```

and this is my ImageAdapter.java file:

```
package com.grid.example;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context myContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        myContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(myContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(4, 0, 4, 0 );
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);


        return imageView;

    }

    // references to our images
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {

            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5
            };

}
```

I tried editing the padding and the horizontalspacing in the main.xml file.
I got the vertical spacing to be just fine. I am just having problems with images to resize so they fit the screen perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to figure out the layout in android xml file i have downloaded AndEngine for android and it worked perfectly for ordering the images so they are right next to one another. It also allows for screen scrolling and is pretty good when it comes to game design. Here is the link if anybody else is interested.

http://andenginefromscratch.blogspot.com/2011/03/introduccion-andengine-parte-i.html

Answer (score 0):

An option to having a hardcoded "image layout" in your code is to create a new layout for your ImageView. You then inflate the layout in your code.

The benefit of that is that you can use the graphicla ui editor to see the properties, see a preview of how the ImageView behaves, and you make it easier to modify the behaviour without modifying the code. (You might e.g. want to have a different layout for other screen sizes)

Update:
You can find an example of how to inflate a view here:
[API Demos, List14](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Im having hard time, however understanding what you mean by hardcoded?  do you mean "programmatic" UI layout? and what meant by inflate the layout in your code. Maybe if you have some bits and pieces of a basic layout code to show me it would be easier to me to understand.

Comment: I updated my reply with a link to an example that inflates a layout.

Answer (score 0):

once try this

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"
    />
```

Comment: Thanks for providing actual code :) this stops the images from overlapping however I want to make the images be stuck right next to each other without overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

As **Kaj** has answered above, i am totally agree with him. Create a row layout file with ImageView only and then inflate the same layout in your ImageAdapter class.

The main advantage of this kind of row xml layout is to have preview of the layout.

And while creating ImageView, be sure you define **`android:scaleType="center"`** so that it display in the center area.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Where can i find the preview of the layout?

Comment: @Xitcod13 don't you get preview while designing layout?

Comment: i got it thanks. Im just so use to editing the xml file by hand i forgot the other tab is even there